# Python: String formatting together with enumerate? (Producing a nice string representation of a polynomial in a pythonic way)

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I started to write a little class that should represent polynomial functions in one variable. I'm aware that the powerful sympy module is out there but I decided that it is simpler to put a few lines of code instead of loading the entire sympy module. The main reason is that simply just uses a level of abstraction (i.e. dealing with variables and rings) that I don't need.

So here is what I did:

```
class Polynomial:
    """Class representing polynomials."""
    
    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
        """Coefficients of the polynomial in the order a_0,...a_n."""
     
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Polynomial(%r)" % self.coefficients
            
    def __call__(self, x):    
        res = 0
        for index, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients):
            res += coeff * x** index
        return res
```

I would like to also implement `__str___` with the same output as produced by the for loop:

```
res = ""
for index, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients):
    res += str(coeff) + "x^"+str(index)
```

First, I expected something like `"$r*x^%r" % enumerate(self.coefficients)` to work but it doesn't. I tried to convert the `enumerate(...)` to tuple but this also didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas for a pythonic, one-line return statement I could use for `__str__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but you can use `str.format` with `str.join` to obtain your string. For example:

```
coefficients = [2, 5, 1, 8]
print( '+'.join('{1}*x^{0}'.format(*v) for v in enumerate(coefficients)) )
```

Prints:

```
2*x^0+5*x^1+1*x^2+8*x^3
```